# Leitura de arquivo CSV e armazenamento de linhas em vetor

Tags: python, csv

Preciso ler um arquivo csv e armazenar cada **linha** do arquivo em vetores diferentes. Após isso, converter esses vetores para novos arquivos csv.

O problema é que meu código gera dois vetores com os dados das **colunas** do csv.

O que estou tentando é:

```py
import os
import csv

os.chdir(r'C:\Users\')

coord1=[]

file = csv.reader(open(arquivo,'r'))
for row in file:
    coord1.append(row[0])
```

O que poderia fazer?

Answer (score -1):

[TL;DR](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-df-values-to-list)

Se entendi direito, voce pode fazer usando o pandas DataFrame para ler o arquivo e então converter os valores para o tipo `list` do Python. Criei um exemplo para mostrar isso, como voce não exemplificou o csv, fiz a simulação de um com apenas 3 colunas e 4 linhas, leio o arquivo para um `DataFrame` e, no final, crio 3 'vetores', um com todas as linhas, e os outros dois alternando uma linha pra cada um.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = ''' 
Nome,Sobrenome,Telefone
Foo,Bar,9-6666-6666
John,Doe,9-7777-7777
Lena,Luthor, 9-8888-8888
Peter,Gabriel, 9-9999-9999
'''

# Lendo o csv 
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), usecols=['Nome', 'Sobrenome', 'Telefone'])

# Imprimindo o resultado
print('\n',df)

print('','Vetor com todas as linhas:', df.values.tolist(), sep='\n')
print('','Vetor com as linhas nas posicoes pares:',df.values.tolist()[::2], sep='\n') 
print('','Vetor com as linhas nas posicoes impares:',df.values.tolist()[1::2], sep='\n')
```

Saída:

```
     Nome Sobrenome      Telefone
0    Foo       Bar   9-6666-6666
1   John       Doe   9-7777-7777
2   Lena    Luthor   9-8888-8888
3  Peter   Gabriel   9-9999-9999

Vetor com todas as linhas:
[['Foo', 'Bar', '9-6666-6666'], ['John', 'Doe', '9-7777-7777'], ['Lena', 'Luthor', ' 9-8888-8888'], ['Peter', 'Gabriel', ' 9-9999-9999']]

Vetor com os elementos nas posicoes pares:
[['Foo', 'Bar', '9-6666-6666'], ['Lena', 'Luthor', ' 9-8888-8888']]

Vetor com os elementos nas posicoes impares:
[['John', 'Doe', '9-7777-7777'], ['Peter', 'Gabriel', ' 9-9999-9999']]

```

[Veja funcionando no repl.it](https://repl.it/@sidonduarte/pandas-df-values-to-list).

Comment: Nossa, para que eu continue tentando ajudar, poderiam explicar porque o downvote?